# How to arrange all the numbers in single list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am listing all the numbers of directories that are present and I tried to arrange all of them in a single list so that I could choose these numbers one by one like `c[n]` but the problem is that it is not arranging all the numbers in a single list.

**Given result**

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

**Expected result**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Code**

```
import os

def select_number(which_path):
  totalFolder = 0
  for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(which_path):
    for dir in dirs:
      totalFolder += 1
      c = [int(x) for x in str(totalFolder)]
      print(str(c))

selected_number('/home/runner/TestP1')
```

Comment: create a list outside the for look `mylist = []` then instead of printing, do `mylist.append(c)` then after the for loop do `print(mylist)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work :

```
def select_number(which_path):
  totalFolder = 0
  c = []
  for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(which_path):
    for dir in dirs:
      totalFolder += 1
      c.append([int(x) for x in str(totalFolder)])
  print(c)
```

You need to agreagate your results in list